# How do I install Mezzanine as a Django app?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I already have an existing Django website. I have added a new url route '/blog/' where I would like to have a Mezzanine blog. If it possible to installed Mezzanine as an app in an existing Django site as opposed to a standalone blog application.

Comment: I have tried this quite a bit with no luck; would like to know how to achieve this too. Mezzanine is a CMS, and it has its only runserver, etc. I believe it is not possible to do this.

Answer (score 13):

If you are like me, you will find that the FAQ is sorely lacking in its description of how to get Mezzanine working as an app. So here is what I did (after a painful half day of hacking) to get it integrated (somewhat):

1. Download the repo and copy it into your project
2. Run setup.py for the package
3. `cd` to the package and run the mezzanine command to create a new app (`mezzanine-project <project name>`), let's say you use the name `blog` as your `<project_name>`.
4. In either the `local_settings.py` or `settings.py` file, set the `DATABASES` dict to use your project's database.
5. Run the `createdb` command from the mezzanine `manage.py` file

---

Now it's time to start the hack-fest:

1. In your project's settings.py file, add `blog` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Add some configuration variables to settings.py that Mezzanine is expecting:

   `PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER = "filebrowser_safe"
   PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe"
   GRAPPELLI_INSTALLED = False
   ADMIN_REMOVAL = []
   RATINGS_RANGE = range(1, 5)
   TESTING = False
   BLOG_SLUG = ''
   COMMENTS_UNAPPROVED_VISIBLE = True
   COMMENTS_REMOVED_VISIBLE = False
   COMMENTS_DEFAULT_APPROVED = True
   COMMENTS_NOTIFICATION_EMAILS = ",".join(ALL_EMAILS)
   COMMENT_FILTER = None`
3. Add some middleware that Mezzanine is expecting:
   ````
   ...
   "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
   "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
   "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
   "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
   "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
   "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",

   ## Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:

   ## "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",

   "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
   ....
   ````
4. Add some INSTALLED_APPS that Mezzanine is expecting:

   `....
   "mezzanine.boot",
   "mezzanine.conf",
   "mezzanine.core",
   "mezzanine.generic",
   "mezzanine.blog",
   "mezzanine.forms",
   "mezzanine.pages",
   "mezzanine.galleries",
   "mezzanine.twitter",
   ....`
5. Add references to the template folders of `mezzanine` to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` tuple

   `os.path.join(BASE_PARENT, '<path to mezzanine>/mezzanine/mezzanine'),
   os.path.join(BASE_PARENT, '<path to mezzanine>/mezzanine/mezzanine/blog/templates'),`
6. Finally, if your like me, you'll have to override some of the `extends` paths in the mezzanine templates, the most obvious being in "blog_post_list.html" which just extends `base.html`, instead you want it to extend the mezzanine specific `base` file. So go to that file and replace the `{% extends "base.html" %}` with `{% extends "core/templates/base.html" %}`.

Comment: Hi, I get this problem when running setup.py:



`from: can't read /var/mail/setuptools
from: can't read /var/mail/shutil
from: can't read /var/mail/mezzanine
./setup.py: line 9: exclude: command not found
./setup.py: line 10: mezzanine/project_template/project_name/local_settings.py]: No such file or directory
./setup.py: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token ('
./setup.py: line 13: exclude = dict([(e, None) for e in exclude])'`

any ideas?

Comment: the above content looks really helpful, but before i spend a bunch of time trying them out, are there any updated steps? i only ask because the answer was posted over three years ago, so i'm not sure how current it is.

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the FAQs:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-can-i-add-mezzanine-to-an-existing-django-project

TLDR: Mezzanine adds a handful of settings, apps, middleware and context processors, all defined in its default settings.py file - you just need to extract enough of those, depending on your needs.